# How do I 'use diagnostics' for Perl on Cygwin?

Tags: perl, cpan

I want to install `DBD::AnyData` which requires `SQL::Statement` which requires `Math::Base::Convert`. However, it's giving me this error

```
$ cpan install Math::Base::Convert
...
t/overload.t .............. couldn't find diagnostic data in /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/pods/perldiag.pod /home/Chloe/.cpan/build/Math-Base-Convert-0.11-EySfLp/blib/lib /home/Chloe/.cpan/build/Math-Base-Convert-0.11-EySfLp/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/5.22 . t/overload.t at /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/diagnostics.pm line 259, <POD_DIAG> line 704.
Compilation failed in require at t/overload.t line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/overload.t line 1.
t/overload.t .............. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/overload.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=20, Tests=5327,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.28 usr  0.01 sys +  0.76 cusr  0.42 csys =  1.48 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/20 test programs. 0/5327 subtests failed.
Makefile:859: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  MIKER/Math-Base-Convert-0.11.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MIKER/Math-Base-Convert-0.11.tar.gz
```

I already ran `cpan -u`.

CPAN version 1.61, Perl 5.22.0

Comment: That's a weird one. Does `perl -Mdiagnostics -e1` give an error?

Comment: I can't even get `perl -e 'use diagnostics;'` to work. I upgraded to 5.22.1 also.

Comment: does cygwin have a package for perldocs that's separate from the package for perl? If so, make sure it's installed.

Comment: @hobbs No, it doesn't have a `perldocs` package.

Comment: @Chloe I found the package list, looks like it's `perl_pods`. Please try installing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `diagnostics` module gets its explanations for messages from the perldoc file `perldiag.pod`. Both of these are core parts of perl, but some packaging systems choose to distribute documentation in a separate package that might not be installed even when perl is. In the case of Cygwin this package is `perl_pods`. Installing that package should make the `diagnostics` module work properly.